# Netbeans 7.01 with Cygwin, debugger won't stop on breakpoints

Tags: netbeans, gdb, cygwin

I presume that the debugger is configured correctly (but what else can it be)?

If I look at Tools/Options/C/C++ it is set up nicely for Cygwin_4.x and the toolset programs all exist (especially C:\cygwin\bin\gdb.exe)  Since I can build and link ok, and this all gets setup by NetBeans discovery of the toolset, I would expect to be able to debug.

The only minor detail is that C:\users\mawg.gdbinit does not exist. I supplied an empty file to no avail. IIRC from form running GDB by hand 20 years ago it isn't necessary.

If I Ctrl+F5 (debug main project (I have only one)) or Alt+F6 (run all test files) the application runs and produces output ... I can also "step into" and proceed with F7 & F8 ...

... but ***it won't stop on breakpoints***.

I guess that I am missing something very simple. Who can point it out to me, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I *could* just delete this question, but I will post the "answer" just so others might have one more thing to check if they have the same problem.

Not being able to debug with Netbans, I tried MS visual studio and it reported that I had an opening

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

without the corresponding close.

This is *not* a NetBeans problem; it is a GCC compiler problem, from GCC of Cygwin, I will report this to GNU/GCC.

Moral: migh be worth checking; but it is always worth running problematic code through a few different compilers and linters.

Comment: I don't understand you at all. You claim that a bug in your source code cased Netbeans to not stop on breakpoints? Do you suggest, that after fixing bug found with MS Visual Studio, Netbeans started to stop on breakpoints? I was more than sure that Netbeans not stopping on breakpoints is purely configuration or IDE problem and it has nothing to do with source code being debugged. Either I'm missing something or you're mixing two completely not related things in one question-answer pair.